# Dynamically Displaying Images via XML file

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file with a list of image names (plus other data)

Example: image1, image2, image3, etc

I am able to load the XML file, parse the results, and loop through the image names.  What I'm having trouble with is retrieving the images from the drawable folder and displaying them on the app.

When the script loops it pulls each image name (ie image1, image2, etc) that matches the image in the drawables folder (ie image1.png, image2.png, etc).  It assigns this name to the ImageNameInXml string.  I want to use this string to assign the ImageView to that drawable and then repeat this (via the loop already in place) for each image showing all images on the screen.

```
   String ImageNameInXml = ghostCamLocation.getAttributeValue(null, XML_TAG);
   ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MyImageView);
   int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageNameInXml , "@drawable/"+ImageNameInXml, getPackageName());
   imgGhostCamLocationTmbnail.setImageResource(resId);
```

The found the above code on stackoverflow to load an image by a string name, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I appreciate the help.

Take care,
Shannon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(ImageNameInXml , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

try this.

Comment: LOL.  I just noticed this as well.  I found another example and you're right it should have been just "drawable".

Comment: The only issue now is that it's not displaying the images one after another.  Are they overlapping?  Am I suppose to add something to offset each image so they display after each other?

Comment: I guess they are overlapping, you must put images in some kind of layout, may be linearLayout.

Comment: They are in a linear layout in the xml file. I've also tried the relative layout as well.  I'm thinking that I need to give a unique name each time I call the ImageView but can't get it to work.

Comment: Anyone know how to have the images display one after another?  I think I need to update the img to be unique for each loop.  Would this display each image separately?  The same thing is happening with any textView as well.  I suspect that because the img name doesn't change it's just overwriting the same ImageView with the new image.  I need a new ImageView created on each loop.  Any ideas?